# Insert to multiple tables with mutiple values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert data to 2 tables. A customer connection table and equipment table. I have a form that defines "source equipment", "source slot and port" and "source FNN" , destination equipment values as well as customer connection values.

I want to insert into 'cust_port' table the source and destination system ports and FNNS as cust_port values as well as the customer connection values.

Please note: Source values can be empty, destination values can be empty, but not both. ie there has to be at least a source and/or destination values.  I don't want blank values being written to equipment table (cust_port) if they are blank.

I have tried multiple inserts but i can't get it to work.

```
try{

$insert_cust_port="INSERT INTO cust_port (
    system_name, 
    slot_no, 
    port_no, 
    port_fnn
    ) VALUES (
    :system_name_source,  
    :slot_source,
    :port_source    
    :source_fnn
    ),( 
    :system_name_dest,
    :slot_dest,
    :port_dest,
    :dest_fnn   
    )";

$insert_cust_conn="INSERT INTO cust_connections (
    short_name, 
    source_fnn, 
    dest_fnn, 
    service_type,
    ladder_side
    ) VALUES (
    :short_name,  
    :source_fnn, 
    :dest_fnn, 
    :service_type,
    :ladder_side    
    )";


//prepare query for excecution
    $database->query($insert_cust_port);

             //bind the parameters
                $database->bind(':system_name_source', $system_name_source );
                $database->bind(':slot_source', $slot_source );
                $database->bind(':port_source', $port_source );
                $database->bind(':source_fnn', htmlentities($source_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':system_name_dest', $system_name_dest );
                $database->bind(':slot_dest', $slot_dest );
                $database->bind(':port_dest', $port_dest );
                $database->bind(':dest_fnn', htmlentities($dest_fnn) );

    $database->query($insert_cust_conn);

             //bind the parameters
                $database->bind(':short_name', $short_name );
                $database->bind(':source_fnn', htmlentities($source_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':dest_fnn', htmlentities($dest_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':source_fnn', htmlentities($source_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':s_type', $s_type );
                $database->bind(':ladder_side', $ladder_side );


// Execute the query
$database->execute(); 
echo "Record was added.";
        header ("location: customer_list.php"); 


}   catch (Exception $e)   
{   
 throw new Exception( 'Something went wrong. Please contact Administrator', 0, $e);   
}
```

Customer connection table:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cust_connections` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `short_name` char(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `source_fnn` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `dest_fnn` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `service_type` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `ladder_side` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    INSERT INTO `cust_connections` (`id`, `short_name`, `source_fnn`, `dest_fnn`, `service_type`, `ladder_side`) VALUES
    (1, 'cust1', 'N2843453A', '', 'HD_300_Connect', 'src only'),
    (2, 'cust2', '', 'N2843600A', 'HD_300_Connect', 'dest only'),
    (3, 'cust3', 'N2720257O', 'N2731164O', 'DVB25_188byte', 'both'),
    (4, 'cust4', 'N27xxx7O', 'N2731164O', 'DVB25_188byte', 'src ukn'),
    (5, 'cust4', 'N27xxx7O', '', 'DVB25_188byte', 'ukn +blk');

ALTER TABLE `cust_connections`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cust_connections`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=18;
```

Customer equipment table:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cust_port` (
    `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
      `system_name` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `slot_no` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `port_no` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `port_fnn` char(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    INSERT INTO `cust_port` (`id`, `system_name`, `slot_no`, `port_no`, `port_fnn`) VALUES
    (1, '01-06C2:source', '7', '1', 'N2843453A'),
    (2, '01-27B4:dest', '1', '2', 'N2843600A'),
    (3, '01-27B6:source+dst', '17', '3', 'N2720257O'),
    (4, '01-27B6:dst+src', '17', '3', 'N2731164O'),
    (5, '01-32C6:dup_fnn1', '1', '2', 'N2845070O'),
    (26, '01-32C6:dup_fnn2', '1', '3', 'N2845070O'),
    (27, '01-32D6:no_fnn', '1', '4', ''),
    (28, '01-32D6:diff_fnn', '1', '4', 'x123456');

ALTER TABLE `cust_port`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cust_port`
MODIFY `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=29;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by splitting the query into 3 inserts:
1st insert for source information to equipment
2nd for destination to equipment 
3rd for customer information.

This makes it easy to check if values are set or not.
I will also set this up to use transactions.

```
try{

$insert_cust_port_source="INSERT INTO cust_port (
    system_name, 
    slot_no, 
    port_no, 
    port_fnn
    ) VALUES (
    :system_name,  
    :slot_no,
    :port_no,   
    :port_fnn
    )";

$insert_cust_port_dest="INSERT INTO cust_port (
    system_name, 
    slot_no, 
    port_no, 
    port_fnn
    ) VALUES (  
    :system_name,  
    :slot_no,
    :port_no,   
    :port_fnn   
    )";

$insert_cust_conn="INSERT INTO cust_connections (
    short_name, 
    source_fnn, 
    dest_fnn, 
    service_type,
    ladder_side
    ) VALUES (
    :short_name,  
    :source_fnn, 
    :dest_fnn, 
    :service_type,
    :ladder_side    
    )";


//prepare query for excecution
    $database->query($insert_cust_port_source);

             //bind the parameters
                $database->bind(':system_name', $system_name_source );
                $database->bind(':slot_no', $slot_source );
                $database->bind(':port_no', $port_source );
                $database->bind(':port_fnn', htmlentities($source_fnn) );
// Execute the query
$database->execute(); 


    $database->query($insert_cust_port_dest);

             //bind the parameters

                $database->bind(':system_name', $system_name_dest );
                $database->bind(':slot_no', $slot_dest );
                $database->bind(':port_no', $port_dest );
                $database->bind(':port_fnn', htmlentities($dest_fnn) );         
// Execute the query
$database->execute(); 


    $database->query($insert_cust_conn);

             //bind the parameters
                $database->bind(':short_name', '$short_name' );
                $database->bind(':source_fnn', htmlentities($source_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':dest_fnn', htmlentities($dest_fnn) );
                $database->bind(':service_type', '$service_type' );
                $database->bind(':ladder_side', '$ladder_side' );
// Execute the query
$database->execute();
```